# Software for capture video in virtual desktop

Tags: screen-recording, windows-10, virtual-desktop

I use **Windows 10** and I need a software to capture just one [virtual desktop](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/04/16/virtual-desktops-in-windows-10-the-power-of-windowsmultiplied/) and when I move to another desktop, that software should still capture video from the first virtual desktop (like capture video from live show or something).

I use **snagIt**, but it only captures the current screen.

<del>Must be free.</del> not necessarily, I'm ok with commercial.

Comment: Technically it should be possible to implement that with [SetThreadDesktop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686250%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Since desktops are a feature of Windows, it should also work with  [SysInternals Desktops](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx) e.g. on Windows 7

Comment: @Thomas I'm not looking for a method or function to create a software, I need to find a software that already do this. Also  `SysInternals Desktops` just add virtual desktop feature to older version of windows.

Comment: That's why it was a comment and not an answer.

Comment: How many monitors do you have on this system

Comment: @AidenGrossman I have one monitor, With two monitor I can simply do this job of course.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/). It supports Windows 7, 8 and 10. It is available for free.

You need to add a monitor capture to your scene and then you should be good to go. The monitor capture will capture your desktop for as long as you tell OBS to capture. You can use hotkeys to start and stop the capture if that is a concern.

Comment: This seems to work if you start capturing on the "real" monitor. You can then switch to a virtual monitor and get back after a while. However, it does not work if the capture is started on a virtual desktop. In my case, the recording was black only with the mouse trail flickering.